# Can not move to variable full response - Groovy Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I encountered in Jmeter that I can not solved.
I want to create a test that send request and get the response.
the response is url encode.
So first I need to put the response in a variable and than to url decode it.
1. I create regex and put the response in variable name "full_response", it saved as expected as you can see in results.
2. I created a groovy sampler step and just want to pass the "full_response" and print it, to know that it is passed OK.
and it is not print all the response just the 3 letters. (I think because the response is URL ENCODE).
Can someone please advise how to pass this variable to groovy script? and than print it?
the purpose is to url decode the results and put assertion on it!!
How I can put the results in "reponse_before_decode" variable in groovy sampler, and than to url decode it.
in the debug sampler I **not** see the response_before_decode variable that I created in the  groovy sampler 
Is it because the response is with special chars? and I can not pass it as whole>? (see the response in full response variable that is with regex)
regards

```
def reponse_before_decode = args[0] as String;
def reponse_before_decode_2 = args[0];

System.out.println ("re" + '$full_response');
System.out.println ("full" + reponse_before_decode_2);
System.out.println ("full" + reponse_before_decode);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your regular expression is off, try something like `full_response=(.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never reference JMeter Variables or Functions in Groovy script like `${full_response}`, use `vars.get('full_response')` instead as it might conflict with [GStringTemplates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine)
2. You don't need Regular Expression Extractor interim step, you can access previous Sampler result from the JSR223 Sampler like:

   ```
   def reponse_before_decode = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString()
   ```

   where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance
3. And finally JMeter comes with [__urlDecode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) which you can use to decode `x-www-form-urlencoded` strings. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.